# Simple average function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, arguments

How could I calculate average using a function:

```
function calculate(array) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + array[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
document.write(calculate([24, 88, 12, 4]));
```

(I don't understand how to get the arguments length)

Comment: Just `return sum / array.length;`?

Comment: array.size() & array.length both have your argument length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the array's length property:

```
function calculate(array) {
    var i = 0, sum = 0, len = array.length;
    while (i < len) {
        sum = sum + array[i++];
    }
    return sum / len;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

To get the average, just sum the values and divide by number of indices in the array, i.e. the length

```js
function calculate(array) {
    return array.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / array.length;
}

console.log(calculate([24, 88, 12, 4]));
```

Answer (score 5):

You can calculate the average easily with `reduce()` method:

```
const avg = array.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / array.length
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function sum all the number in the array. in the return line you should change to something like this:

```
return sum / array.length;
```

And you should change this line:

```
console.log(calculate([24, 88, 12, 4]));
```

to this:

```
console.log(calculate({24, 88, 12, 4}));
```

Comment: `lenght` should be `length`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way as well by using **for-of** loop.

```
function average(...nums) {
    let total = 0;
    for(const num of nums) {
    total += num/nums.length;
    }
    return total;
}
console.log(average(24, 88, 12, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

This **for...of** loop should work perfectly

```
function average(...nums) {
    let sum = 0;
    let avg = 0;

    for(const num of nums) {
    sum += num;
    avg = sum/nums.length;
    }

    return avg;
}
console.log(average(24, 88, 12, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
x = []
function average(...x) {
    let sum = 0,
        avg = 0;
    for (let i of x ){
        sum = sum + i;
        avg = sum/x.length;
    }
    
    return avg
}

console.log(average(2, 6 , 8 , 14));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).